# regex numbers and decimal points

Tags: c#, regex

Could any of you help me with a regex to allow this:

```
123.123
123.
1323.2
1.2312
1,23
123123,32
123,
123412
```

so to sum up: only one decimal point, it can be the last one.. but most not be the first.

but not this:

```
12.323.323
1213..
12331...3123
.12313
,123132
```

Comment: less `Regex` more `Parse` I'd suggest.

Comment: Try `decimal.Parse` or `double.Parse`

Comment: What about `123` (without any decimal point)? Is it allowed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work

`^\d+[\.,]?\d*$`

`^` start of the string
`\d+` 1 or more digits
`[\.,]?` 0 or 1 decimal or comma
`\d*` 0 or more digits
`$` end of string.

Comment: woops.. made a mistake.. the decimal or comma has to be optional..

Comment: Okay, I've changed it back

Comment: Decimal points don't have to be escaped when within a range `[.,]` unless that varies on implementation and I don't know,

Answer (score 2):

```
\b\d+(\.|,)\d*\b
```

which means:

```
a word boundary
a digit one or more times
a `.` or a `,`
a digit zero or more times
a word boundary
```

The word boundaries are there to prevent the regex matching from the middle of a number

Comment: This is a simple one but it will also match a , or . by itself. To handle that case you need to change it to handle the separate cases (digits, in front, after or both). I will leave that up to you as modifying this regex will help you to understand it

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works with all cases that you mention.

(\d+)(((\.|,)\d+)|,))

Comment: You need to escape the `.` with `\.`, or it will match things like 123a123.

Comment: I test it here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
and it works !

Answer (score 0):

My fix for your regex: (\d+)(((.|,)\d+)|,)?
Added '?' to end, it will works for zero value